# Variable undefined inside JavaScript For-In loop

Tags: javascript, object, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, for-in-loop

I stumbled upon this puzzling error when looping over JavaScript objects using the `for..in` construct. I have a set of dummy data similar to this:

```
{
  "12345678" : {
    ...
  },
  "12345679" : {
    ...
  },
  "12345680" : {
    ...
  }
}
```

Maybe it matters, this object is retrieved from a Firebase database using the response's built-in `.val()` method. It is a regular js object.

However, when traversing the object, the variable declared *inside* the `for..in` loop is somehow undefined. I've removed all surrounding code except the loop, and the error still occurs:

```
for (key in data) {
 console.log(data[key]);
}
// Throws ReferenceError: key is not defined
```

I am really baffled. How is this possible? I thought the variable passed to `for..in` was always available (or at least defined) inside the loop.

Comment: Did you define `key` somewhere? Like `for (var key in data)`? Also, have you tried printing out `data` with something like `JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)`?

Comment: Huh, that was silly. Didn't declare as `var` anywhere. I've been messing around with this for half an hour now. I guess it's time for bed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you'll probably need to define `key`; otherwise, you'll (probably) define a global variable, which may or may not work correctly. Also, to avoid unrelated properties from appearing in your loop, use `hasOwnProperty`:

```
for (var key in data) {
    if (!data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        continue;
    }

    console.log(data[key]);
}
```

See [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object) for further information.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `hasOwnProperty`. The initial error was an oversight, but this is something I should actually start using.

Answer (score 2):

you just don't use the right syntax for `for..in` statement.
You need to define `key` variable with `var` (or `let` if you use ES6): in order to use it in the statement:

```
for(var key in data){
  console.log(data[key])
}
```

Comment: That was it, thanks! I think it's time for sleep when one starts overlooking stuff like this. :)